# How to check whether a string contains today's date in a specific format

Tags: ruby, string, rss

I'm parsing some RSS feeds that aggregate what's going on in a given city. I'm only interested in the stuff that is happening today.

At the moment I have this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rss/1.0'
require 'rss/2.0'
require 'open-uri'
require 'shorturl'

source = "http://rss.feed.com/example.xml"
content = ""
open(source) do |s| content = s.read end
rss = RSS::Parser.parse(content, false)

t = Time.now
day = t.day.to_s
month = t.strftime("%b")

rss.items.each do |rss|
  if "#{rss.title}".include?(day)&&(month)
    # does stuff with it
  end
end
```

Of course by checking whether the title (that I know contains the date of event in the following format: "(2nd Apr 11)") contains the day and the month (eg. '2' and 'May') I get also info about the events that happen on 12th May, 20th of May and so on. How can I make it foolproof and only get today's events?

Here's a sample title: "Diggin Deeper @ The Big Chill House (12th May 11)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
today = Time.now.strftime("%d:%b:%y")
if date_string =~ /(\d*).. (.*?) (\d\d)/
  article_date = sprintf("%02i:%s:%s", $1.to_i, $2, $3)
  if today == article_date
    #this is today
  else
    #this is not today
  end
else
  raise("No date found in title.")
end
```

There could potentially be problems if the title contains other numbers.  Does the title have any bounding characters around the date, such as a hyphen before the date or brackets around it?  Adding those to the regex could prevent trouble.  Could you give us an example title?  (An alternative would be to use Time#strftime to create a string which would perfectly match the date as it appears in the title and then just use String#include? with that string, but I don't think there's an elegant way to put the 'th'/'nd'/'rd'/etc on the day.)

Comment: Yes, there are parentheses around the date. Using regular expressions seems a very elegant solution.

Comment: I have added the sample title to the question to clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
def check_day(date)
  t = Time.now
  day = t.day.to_s
  month = t.strftime("%b")

  if date =~ /^#{day}nd\s#{month}\s11/
    puts "today!"
  else
    puts "not today!"
  end
end

check_day "3nd May 11" #=> today!
check_day "13nd May 11" #=> not today!
check_day "30nd May 11" #=> not today!
```